# mongodb: Return subdocument and keep track of parent

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of tweets and I am trying to output the retweets on root level (similarly for quoted tweets) to a new collection to merge them later with the original collection using dump and restore).
The retweeted status is a subdocument in the tweet document, and there may be multiple tweets retweeting the same tweet. 
How can I make the retweet on the root level and add an array called 'retweeted_by' that contains the ids of all tweets that retweeted it?

keeping in mind that I am using the tweet id as the primary index (_id) to avoid creating duplicates when combining (mongorestore) collections.

My collection has the form:

```
{
    "_id" : "123456",
    "other_fields1" : "values1",
    "retweeted_status" : {
                          "retweet_id": "159753",
                          "other_fields2" : "values2",
                          }
}
```

The ideal output is expected to look like:

```
{
    "_id" : "159753",
    "other_fields2" : "values2",    
    "retweeted_by" : [ "123456", "974631", "121212"]
}
```

**edit for clarification:**

The fields in the subdocument (other_fields2) are multiple fields (~28) that are not all present in other tweets

Comment: `db.collection.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$retweeted_status.retweet_id", retweeted_by: {$push: "$_id"}}}])`

Comment: @felix thanks, but this only outputs the id of the retweeted_status, not the whole subdocument of retweeted_status, called in my sample "other_fields2"... I think after the grouping I need to use $replaceRoot with the subdocument as a newRoot and somehow add to it the array retweeted_by

Comment: add `other_fields2: {$first: "$retweeted_status.other_fields2"}`. please take a look at [mongodb documentation $group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

Comment: @felix I tried that, but the problem is that other_fields2 is actually multiple fields (between 24-28 fields) that differ from one retweet to another, i.e one can have 24 fields, another can have an additional 4 fields

Comment: @felix I think I figured out the solution to my question. I am new to asking questions here, so what is the best approach: shall i post the solution, or delete the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.. so I finally reached a solution to my question.. I am not sure if this is the best way to do it though:

```
db.tweets.aggregate([
{
    $match: { retweeted_status: {$exists: true}} 
},
{ 
    $addFields: { 'retweeted_status.retweeted_by' : '$_id', 'retweeted_status._id' : '$retweeted_status.id_str'} 
},
{
   $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$retweeted_status'} 
},
{ 
    $group: { _id: '$_id',  doc: { '$first': '$$ROOT' }, retweeted_by: {$addToSet: '$retweeted_by'}}
},
{
    $addFields: { 'doc.retweeted_by' : '$retweeted_by'}
},
{
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$doc'}
},
{
    $project: { id: 0 , id_str: 0 }
},
{
    $out: 'retweets'
}
], {allowDiskUse: true})
```

Initially each document (tweet) has the form:

**{parent, {subdocument}}**

First match the existence of a retweeted_status (subdocument), then before grouping by retweeted_status id, I added a field with the id of the parent tweet:

**{parent, {subdocument , parent_id}}**

Then replaced the root with the modified subdocument:

**{subdocument, parent_id}**

Then, I grouped by the new root's _id, took the first document of the group, and added a new accumulator set(retweeted_by). (not $push because twitter API sometimes sends duplicates)

So far the root document contains _id, the retweeted document embedded inside the field 'doc', and an array that contains the parents:

**{doc{subdocument, parent_id}, [parent_ids]}**

Next, I added the parents array as a field inside doc, (overwriting the previously added retweeted_by field):

**{doc{subdocument, [parent_ids]}, [parent_ids]}**

Then replaced the parent (root) with the new doc. then excluded fields that contain the same number as _id:

**{subdocument, [parent_ids]}**